# How to make proper rest call with FamilyAsyncNotifier in Flutter Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have an FamilyAsyncNotifier as follow:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';


class LoginResponse {
  final String token;
  final String refresh_token;

  LoginResponse({required this.token, required this.refresh_token});

  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return LoginResponse(
      token: json['token'],
      refresh_token: json['refresh_token'],
    );
  }
}

class LoginParam extends Equatable {
  final String userName;
  final String userPassword;

  const LoginParam({required this.userName, required this.userPassword});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [userName, userPassword];
}

class AppLoginNotifier extends FamilyAsyncNotifier<LoginResponse, LoginParam> {

  FutureOr<LoginResponse> doLogin(String userName, String userPassword) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 20));
    return LoginResponse(token: userName, refresh_token: userPassword);
  }

  @override
  FutureOr<LoginResponse> build(LoginParam arg) async {
    return doLogin(arg.userName, arg.userPassword);
  }
}

final appLoginProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider.family<AppLoginNotifier, LoginResponse, LoginParam>(AppLoginNotifier.new);
```

and i call this from my app:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'loginNotifier.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home:  MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  final TextEditingController userNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    
    return Scaffold(
        body: Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded( 
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextField(
                      controller: userNameController,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    TextField(
                      controller: passwordController,
                      obscureText: true,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 30),
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 35,
                      decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                        shape: StadiumBorder(),
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                          end: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          colors: [
                            Color.fromARGB(255, 195, 1, 1),
                            Color.fromARGB(255, 148, 0, 0)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                        shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                        child: const Text(
                          'Login',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          return ref.read(appLoginProvider(LoginParam(userName: userNameController.text, userPassword: passwordController.text))).when(data: (LoginResponse v) => debugPrint(v.token), error: (err, stack) => debugPrint(err.toString()), loading: ()=> debugPrint('loading'));
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

When i run the app and click the login button it don't print token as expected, but the second click and subsequent does it. It also happen when i change the username. First click after username change don't show anything but the second and so on does.

Comment: Where are you ref.watch on the appLoginProvider?  Nothing is subscribed to it, unless I missed that.

Comment: I think you are looking for ref.read on login button click. If i don't subscribe to appLoginProvider, i think second click or subsequently will do nothing at all.

Comment: ref.read does not subscribe.  ref.watch does.  In the absence of ref.watch (or ref.listen), a notifier can emit all day and nobody will notice or care *or refresh*.